# Populating Listbox with Data from DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, listbox

I've got 2 forms. Form A has a listbox and a Combobox. Form B has a DataGridView. In my A, my combobox is meant to represent groups for a task. e.g. Inbox, Important etc. So whenever I select an item from the comobobox e.g. I select the "Inbox" Item the DataGridViewer will sort all the rows which contain "Inbox" in one of the columns. This all works fine. I can view the sorted data.

To Load my data into the DataGridView I use:

```
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim dataset1 As New DataSet("datasetTasks")
Dim table1 As New DataTable("tableTask")
Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ds = CreateDataset()
    frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tableTask")
    LoadFromXMLfile("C:\Users\Beta4K\Documents\Tasks.FILE")
    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dr("TaskName").ToString())
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub LoadFromXMLfile(filename As String)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        Dim xmlSerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(ds.GetType)
        Dim readStream As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)
        ds = CType(xmlSerializer.Deserialize(readStream), DataSet)
        readStream.Close()
        frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tableTask")
    Else
        MsgBox("file not found! add data and press save button first.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "")
    End If
End Sub
Private Function CreateDataset() As DataSet
    table1.Columns.Add("TaskID")
    table1.Columns.Add("TaskName")
    table1.Columns.Add("TaskMessage")
    table1.Columns.Add("TaskDate")
    table1.Columns.Add("TaskTime")
    table1.Columns.Add("TaskGroup")
    dataset1.Tables.Add(table1)
    Return dataset1
End Function
```

Here's the code for my Combobox:

```
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim dv As New DataView(ds.Tables("tableTask"))
    dv.RowFilter = "TaskGroup = '" + ComboBox1.SelectedItem + "'"
    frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable("tableTask")
    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dr("TaskName").ToString())
    Next
```

What this is meant to do is that it clears the listbox, and then reloads the items into the listbox from reading all the data in the DataGridViewer. Since it's already sorted all it has to do is add the items but it doesn't. Instead it just adds all the items regardless of the filter.

Can someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop over the datatable while you need to loop over the dataview

```
For Each dr As DataRowView In dv
    ListBox1.Items.Add(dr("TaskName").ToString())
Next
```